# Where to find old Microsoft support packages?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, atl

I need some hotfixes for VS2008 while developing for WinCE 7. Unfortunately, all Microsoft links are 404 dead. Is there any living repository of these out there? For now, all google searches yielded the same dead links...

http://rogeriodossantos.github.io/VisualStudio2008andWindowsCompactEmbedded7-ATLUpdate/

Answer (score 0):

The search terms `"monthly update"` and `"update rollup"` will often yield decent results.

Alternatively, much as I dislike having to rely on third-party sites for this kind of thing, the [kbupdate](http://kbupdate.info/windows-embedded-compact-7-u.php) site seems to have got a fairly complete list.

Comment: Unfortunately, this page directed me to the same Microsoft page, where the download link is broken.